Rotation Proxy not change ip untill exit my app and relaunch it
i`m using rotation proxy for my C# httpclient requests the problem is i got proxed it just one and not changeing every time i request web untill i exit program and launch it again i got a new one but i want to get a new it every request
 public static string GetIPAddress()
        {
            String address = "";
            while (true)
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
                request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://gw.dataimpulse.com:823");              
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    address = stream.ReadToEnd();
                }
                int first = address.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
                int last = address.LastIndexOf("</body>");
                address = address.Substring(first, last - first);
            }
            return address;
        }

here code should every request get a new ip from my proxy

I'm sort of overall confused about what you're trying to do here. What's with the while (true)?

its just for looping while debugging to see every time the code executed the new ip , i denpend on debugging
